# "AWS Amplify Question" Access Token is not working

Tags: python, flutter, amazon-web-services, boto3, amazon-cognito

I want to use access token(from flutter amplify) in python code.

But It doen't work.

**Problem**

I followed [official docs.](https://docs.amplify.aws/javascript/tools/cli/start/set-up-cli/#configure-the-amplify-cli) everything is default state.

I get access token from flutter amplify auth.

```
final cognitoPlugin = Amplify.Auth.getPlugin(AmplifyAuthCognito.pluginKey);
final result = await cognitoPlugin.fetchAuthSession(
  options: CognitoSessionOptions(getAWSCredentials: true),
);

safePrint(
    "result.userPoolTokensResult.value: ${result.userPoolTokensResult.value.accessToken.encode()}");
```

then, I get access token(JWT) like this

```
I/flutter (28465): result.userPoolTokensResult.value: eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImtpZCI6Inc0NzZpQXl5REdRZVZOTjExTCtaS0V3blFmaHE1cmdCaDI0NlhRSnZUVDA9In0.eyJhdXR....
```

I want to verify this access token in python code.
so i use boto3 like this

```
import boto3

# Initialize a boto3 client for Cognito Identity Provider
client = boto3.client('cognito-idp', region_name='ap-northeast-2')
access_token = 'eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImtp....' # access token from flutter amplify

response = client.get_user(AccessToken=access_token)
```

In this code, I get error at client.get_user() function.

```
The token is no longer valid or was not issued for this purpose.
```

**My Trial**

1. create Access Token from python(not amplify)
   I used this code to make token in python

```
import json
import requests
import hmac
import hashlib
import base64

client_id = "5t5t573..." #same client id with flutte amplify configure

cognito_url = "https://cognito-idp.ap-northeast-2.amazonaws.com"
username = "*****"
password = "*****"


reqData = {
    "AuthParameters": {
        "USERNAME": username,
        "PASSWORD": password,
    },
    "AuthFlow": "USER_PASSWORD_AUTH",
    "ClientId": client_id
}

headers = {
    "X-Amz-Target": 'AWSCognitoIdentityProviderService.InitiateAuth',
    "Content-Type": 'application/x-amz-json-1.1'
}

jsonResponse = requests.post(
    url=cognito_url, data=json.dumps(reqData), headers=headers).json()

id_token = jsonResponse['AuthenticationResult']['IdToken']

print(jsonResponse['AuthenticationResult']['AccessToken'])
```

i get token successfuly and tried this token with same code.

```
import boto3

# Initialize a boto3 client for Cognito Identity Provider
client = boto3.client('cognito-idp', region_name='ap-northeast-2')
access_token = 'eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImtp....' # access token from flutter amplify

response = client.get_user(AccessToken=access_token)
```

This time, get_user() function works well.

**Question**

why flutter amplify doesn't work with boto3 get_user() function??

why only it works with token from python???

I centainly use same user pool. I can't understand this error.

Please help me. thank you